# ¿actualizar tabla atraves de un disparador, con operaciones matematicas mysql?

Tags: mysql

estoy intentando actualizar una tabla depues de insertar datos alli, para no tener que hacerlo desde java.
esta es la tabla en la que quiero aplicar el disparador:
[image: tabla dtnombrepresencia]

este es el disparador:

[image: triggers]

lo que queiro hacer en mi tabla es que despues de insertar todos los datos a excepción del `promedio_viaje_td`
se haga lo siguiente; que la nueva `cantidad_td`se multiple por 100 y luego dividirla por el nuevo`tamano_muestra` y se actualice en el campo `promedio_viaje_td`. tal como se muestra en el disparador.

pero me aroja el siguiente error:

[image: error]

este seria un ejemplo de lo que deberia pasar en esa tabla:

**nota:** el id es auto_increment y la fecha_registro esta configurada para que toma la hora del servidor, por eso no hago un insert de esos dos campos.

```
 INSERT INTO dtnombrepresencia (cod_fknombre_plantas,cod_nombre_entidades,tamano_muestra,cantidad_td) VALUES(2,1,100,10);
INSERT INTO dtnombrepresencia (cod_fknombre_plantas,cod_nombre_entidades,tamano_muestra,cantidad_td) VALUES(3,2,90,25);
```

depues de eso el disparador deberia activarse (aqui haria la operacion matematica).

primeros datos insertados:

**tamano_muestra=100
cantidad_td=10**

segundos datos insertados:

**tamano_muestra=90
cantidad_td=25**

esto es lo que disparador deberia hacer:

**@tl=(tamano_muestra*100)/cantidad_td)**

```
update dtnombrepresencia UPDATE dtnombrepresencia SET new.promedio_viaje_td=@tl WHERE new.cod_dt=NEW.cod_dt;
```

este seria el resultado final con una consulta `select * from dtnombrepresencia`:

```
cod_dt | fecha_registro | cod_fknombre_plantas | cod_nombre_entidades| tamano_muestra | cantidad_td| promedio_viaje_td
  1    | 2019-12-29     |               2      |                 1   |      100       |        10  |             10
  2    | 2019-12-29     |               3      |                 2   |       90       |        25  |             27,78
```

entonces no sè, si puede hacer lo que planteo o tiene que hacerce directamente desde java, o que estare haciendo mal, les agradesco sus ayudas, gracias.

este es sql de la bd

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 29-12-2019 a las 10:07:03
-- Versión del servidor: 10.4.10-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 7.3.12

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `pruebas`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura Stand-in para la vista `contador_fecha`
-- (Véase abajo para la vista actual)
--
CREATE TABLE `contador_fecha` (
);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `dtnombrepresencia`
--

CREATE TABLE `dtnombrepresencia` (
  `cod_dt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_registro` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `cod_fknombre_plantas` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cod_nombre_entidades` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tamano_muestra` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cantidad_td` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `promedio_viaje_td` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Disparadores `dtnombrepresencia`
--
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `dtnombrepresencia_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `dtnombrepresencia` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET @tl=((NEW.cantidad_td*100)/NEW.tamano_muestra);
    UPDATE dtnombrepresencia SET new.promedio_viaje_td=@tl WHERE new.cod_dt=NEW.cod_dt;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura Stand-in para la vista `fecha_detalle`
-- (Véase abajo para la vista actual)
--
CREATE TABLE `fecha_detalle` (
);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `nombreplantas`
--

CREATE TABLE `nombreplantas` (
  `cod_nombre_plantas` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_plantas` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `nombreplantas`
--

INSERT INTO `nombreplantas` (`cod_nombre_plantas`, `nombre_plantas`) VALUES
(1, 'RECEPCION Y SACRIFICIO'),
(2, 'ENTRADA DE LA PELADORA'),
(3, 'SALIDA DE LA PELADORA');

--
-- Disparadores `nombreplantas`
--
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `nombreplantas_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `nombreplantas` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET @nombreplantass =(SELECT COUNT(nombreplantas.nombre_plantas)
        FROM nombreplantas WHERE nombreplantas.nombre_plantas = NEW.nombre_plantas);
    IF @nombreplantass > 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'NO SE PUEDE REGISTRAR, YA SE ENCUENTRA EN LA BD';
    END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `nombres_entidades`
--

CREATE TABLE `nombres_entidades` (
  `cod_entidad_presencia` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_ep` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `nombres_entidades`
--

INSERT INTO `nombres_entidades` (`cod_entidad_presencia`, `nombre_ep`) VALUES
(1, 'PRESENCIA DE ALAS FRACTURADAS'),
(2, 'PRESENCIA DE MUSLOS FRACTURADOS'),
(3, 'PRESENCIA DE PIEL RASGADA');

--
-- Disparadores `nombres_entidades`
--
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `nombreentidades_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `nombres_entidades` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET @nombreentidades =(SELECT COUNT(nombres_entidades.nombre_ep) 
        FROM nombres_entidades WHERE nombres_entidades.nombre_ep = NEW.nombre_ep);
    IF @nombreentidades > 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'NO SE PUEDE REGISTRAR, YA SE ENCUENTRA EN LA BD';
    END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura para la vista `contador_fecha`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `contador_fecha`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `contador_fecha`  AS  select `fecha`.`fechas` AS `fecha`,count(`fecha`.`fechas`) AS `total_repetidas` from `fecha` group by `fecha`.`fechas` having count(0) > 0 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura para la vista `fecha_detalle`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fecha_detalle`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `fecha_detalle`  AS  select `fecha`.`fechas` AS `fecha`,count(`fecha`.`fechas`) AS `fechas_repetidas`,sum(`fecha`.`asistentes`) AS `total_asisten_por_fecha` from `fecha` group by `fecha`.`fechas` order by `fecha`.`fechas` ;

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `dtnombrepresencia`
--
ALTER TABLE `dtnombrepresencia`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cod_dt`),
  ADD KEY `cod_nombre_entidades` (`cod_nombre_entidades`),
  ADD KEY `cod_fknombre_plantas` (`cod_fknombre_plantas`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `nombreplantas`
--
ALTER TABLE `nombreplantas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cod_nombre_plantas`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `nombres_entidades`
--
ALTER TABLE `nombres_entidades`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cod_entidad_presencia`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `dtnombrepresencia`
--
ALTER TABLE `dtnombrepresencia`
  MODIFY `cod_dt` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=10;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `nombreplantas`
--
ALTER TABLE `nombreplantas`
  MODIFY `cod_nombre_plantas` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `nombres_entidades`
--
ALTER TABLE `nombres_entidades`
  MODIFY `cod_entidad_presencia` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=9;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `dtnombrepresencia`
--
ALTER TABLE `dtnombrepresencia`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_dtnombrepresencia_nombreplantas` FOREIGN KEY (`cod_fknombre_plantas`) REFERENCES `nombreplantas` (`cod_nombre_plantas`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_dtnombrepresencia_nombres_entidades` FOREIGN KEY (`cod_nombre_entidades`) REFERENCES `nombres_entidades` (`cod_entidad_presencia`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Por favor, utiliza la opción de exportar para enviarnos un dataset en SQL que contenga unos datos de ejemplo y el resultado que esperas obtener a partir de éstos

Comment: es simple bro, mira alli donde sale el error hay un campo que estoy intentado insertar, tamano_muetra=100 y cantidad_td=10 el resultado debe ser 10  esta es la operacion matematica (10*100)/100=10 y quiero que se guarde en el campo promedio_viaje_td. asi mismo para cada registro que vaya insertando.

Comment: No es una cuestión de complejidad, sino de dejarlo correctamente documentado para que les resulte útil a más miembros de la comunidad con una duda similar. De ahí que lo primero sea reproducir el mismo fallo que estás encontrando :)

Comment: ok, listo bro ya lo actualize

Comment: En phpmyadmin tienes una opción de exportar que te genera un fichero en SQL que puedes pegar aquí. En éste están todos los querys necesarios para replicar tu base de datos e intentar resolver lo que planteas: estructura de las tablas, el disparados que has intentando generar, etc

Comment: listo ya agre el sql de mi bd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya sé que te está pasando. Este error se produce porque estás intentando modificar los datos de una tabla que aún no han sido registrados porque el disparador aún está actuando:

> Can't update table 'dtnombrepresencia' in stored function/trigger
>   because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
>   function/trigger.

Prueba así:

```
DROP TRIGGER dtnombrepresencia_after_insert;
CREATE TRIGGER dtnombrepresencia_after_insert
    BEFORE INSERT ON dtnombrepresencia
    FOR EACH ROW
        SET NEW.promedio_viaje_td=NEW.cantidad_td*100/NEW.tamano_muestra;
```

Ten en cuenta que, si intentas modificar un dato AFTER INSERT, te encontrarás con un error del tipo:

> Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

De ahí que también haya sido necesario cambiar el `AFTER` por el `BEFORE`.

Comment: no me deje guardar el trigger probandolo a tu manera, me sae este error. error de SQL(1303): Can't create a TRIGGER from within another stored routine.

Comment: osea como podria crear un disparador que se elimine y se cree asi mismo.

Comment: Con el `DROP TRIGGER` que he puesto antes del `CREATE`, ¿no te ha funcionado?

Comment: no, estoy usando heidisql, pero me sale el error que te comente anteriormente

Comment: Son dos instrucciones diferentes. Primero ejecutas el `DROP` y después el `CREATE`

Comment: creo que si funciona, lo hice por consola y alli si funciono, por heidysql me daba error. si bro funciona, gracias.

Comment: Ah, ya te entiendo... no, no te va a salir ese error porque no estás haciendo un `UPDATE`, sino asignando un valor a uno de los campos antes del `INSERT`. Pruébalo, ya verás...

Comment: si bro, funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102662/discussion-between-cris19n-and-david-jp).